# Can our beliefs change without reassessment or new evidence?

Tags: belief

Can our beliefs change without reassessment or new evidence?

I think the strength of our beliefs can change, say from 90-95% as the day wore on. But do people, people with or without psychosis, start and stop believing things without reasons?

Suppose when I stop and think I always know something is impossible. Does that mean, even in the throes of some irrational behaviour (I sleep with my cheating wife again), I know it is, at least without encountering new evidence to the contrary?

---

As has been pointed out, how we feel about things may change without new evidence, and our feelings can change what we believe. Does that mean we have to "reassess" something in order to be overwhelmed by emotion and new belief?

> Appraisal theory is the theory in psychology that emotions are
> extracted from our evaluations (appraisals or estimates) of events
> that cause specific reactions in different people. Essentially, our
> appraisal of a situation causes an emotional, or affective, response
> that is going to be based on that appraisal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appraisal_theory

So e.g. if my newly discovered emotions of desire for my wife cause me to believe in her fidelity, is that always from an appraisal or reappraisal of some possibility (her fidelity, our future together...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone can choose to change their beliefs without reassessment or new evidence at any time.

These choices can be made without reasons, assessment and reassessment but at the same time, they **can** involve reasons, assessment and reassessment. Again, there is a choice on whether to assess and/or reassess.

There are many [cognitive biases and heuristics which can be in play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases#Belief,_decision-making_and_behavioral).

As an example, you can be presented with evidence contradicting preconceived ideas and initially change your beliefs. But, if you later apply, say, [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) —

> The tendency to search for, interpret, focus on and remember information in a way that confirms one's preconceptions

because you maybe don't want to believe the opposite, you may stick with the previous beliefs and go on the search for evidence to back up your preconceptions.

See the full list of [cognitive biases and heuristics which can be in play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases#Belief,_decision-making_and_behavioral) because:

> Cognitive biases are systematic patterns of deviation from norm and/or rationality in judgment.

Above all, you cannot change your beliefs without wanting to.

For example, a devout Christian would not want to disbelieve something written in the Bible. But, if they were presented with contradictory evidence, they have a choice.

Do they just shrug it off and disbelieve that false information is in the good book? Or, do they at least start to doubt it's accuracies?

If they start to doubt the Bible, do they look at the evidence and believe it, or do they try to discredit it with stronger evidence, which backs the biblical account?

If they don't find it, what do they believe?

There may be unconscious biases in play with some beliefs ([Marcelin, et al. 2019](https://doi.org/10.1093/infdis/jiz214), [Fiarman, 2016](http://files.partnership-academy.net/200002623-049ce0690e/Unconscious%20Bias_Educational%20Leadership.pdf), [Page, 2009](https://ecollections.law.fiu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1379&context=faculty_publications)) but, ultimately there are choices involved.

### References

Fiarman, S. E. (2016). Unconscious bias: When good intentions aren’t enough. *Educational Leadership, 74*(3), 10-15. http://files.partnership-academy.net/200002623-049ce0690e/Unconscious%20Bias_Educational%20Leadership.pdf

Marcelin, J. R., Siraj, D. S., Victor, R., Kotadia, S., & Maldonado, Y. A. (2019). The impact of unconscious bias in healthcare: how to recognize and mitigate it. *The Journal of infectious diseases, 220*(Supplement_2), S62-S73 https://doi.org/10.1093/infdis/jiz214

Page, A. (2009). Unconscious bias and the limits of director independence. *University of Illinois Law Review*, 237-294. https://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/unilllr2009&div=9&id=&page=

Comment: This brings us to the question: what make a choice? What is the relationship between choice and belief? Would under a new, different social norm, new choice forms? I'm thinking about the theory of planned behavior here. (Just some quick questions reading your answer. Perhaps they need to be on a different question post)

Comment: Philosophically speaking, you believe something because you think it's true. So if there is a reason for you to think it's true, its truthfulness will always attract you, regardless of what you choose to believe. The cognitive dissonance leaves you no choice but to keep thinking about it I suppose

Comment: @anon - If you feel you **need** a paper on the fact you choose what you believe, look at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2802367